# Динамические строки, их ввод

Tags: c

Пытаюсь придумать, как заполнить строку (динамически выделенную) неизвестной длины с консоли.

Вот к чему я пришел:

```
str = (char*)calloc(1, 1);
    c2 = 0;

    while (1==1)
    {
        sim = getchar();
        
        if (sim != '\n')
            str[c2] = sim;
        else
            break;

        c2++;
        str = (char*)realloc(str, c2+1);
    }
```

`str` - строка для ввода
т.е я читаю посимвольно и выделяю память для каждого символа, который перед помещением в строку храниться в `sim`.

В итоге `getchar()` остановился на **`\n`**, что печально, ведь я хотел еще считать неопределенное количество строк и записывать в массив строк. Можно использовать `string`, но меня интересует чистый *Си*.

И второй момент: когда я выделяю память под строку в ней находиться какой-то мусор!! Хотя я делал так - `str = new char[0 или 1];` 
Хрень какая-то. Можете помочь с решением двух проблем. Заранее спасибо

И еще, как ввести символ нулевой строки(признак конца строки) в *Windows*?

Comment: Образец для подражания: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/main/src/cs50.c#L78

Answer (score 1):

1. Все же `realloc` для каждого символа (а работа с памятью довольно дорогостояща в плане эффективности) вариант тяжелый. Может, задуматься о, например, удвоении памяти, если ее не хватает?
2. Что значит *`getchar()` остановился*? Вы ввели строку, она пошла в буфер ввода, пошло считывание, последний введенный символ `\n`, работает `break`. Все, как вы попросили. Приступайте к новому чтению очередной строки.
3. Мусор будет находиться и при вызове `malloc`, например. *Выделенная память не очищается*, если только вы не сделали это самостоятельно или не вызвали специальную функцию выделения с очисткой, как это сделано у вас.
4. Нулевой символ в Windows вводится в строку точно так же, как и в любой другой операционной системе — присваиванием типа `str[i] = '\0'` или просто `str[i] = 0`.